# showing output from two tables but matching them via 3rd table

Tags: mysql, database, join, sqlcommand

Suppose i have three table. first table got wine_name and wine_id, 2nd table got wine_id,varie_id and the 3rd table got variety_id and variety_name. I just want to show the wine name with the variety name. I tried inner join but cdnt get the result, jst getting error. can some suggest me what should i write.

Comment: Post your query that produces an error along with the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT w.wine_name, v.variety_name
  FROM wine_variety wv JOIN wines w
    ON wv.wine_id = w.wine_id JOIN varieties v
    ON wv.variety_id = v.variety_id
```

Sample output:

```
| WINE_NAME | VARIETY_NAME |
----------------------------
|    Wine 1 |    Variety 1 |
|    Wine 2 |    Variety 2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1bd0/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
select table1.wine_name, table3.variety_name from table1 inner join 
    table2 on table1.wine_id = table2.wineid left
        join table3 on table2.varieId = table3.varietyID
```